# Send messages asynchronously using Django Channels as they are generated

Tags: django, python-asyncio, django-channels

I've a process that receives data asynchronously using httpx, and I would like to send this data as soon as it is received. Instead Channels only sends it once all the data is received. Not sure if there is something basic I've misunderstood but I'd have thought this would be bread and butter functionality for an asynchronous framework.

I'm using channels in memory layer, and don't have the option to install Redis server, besides based on other questions on stackoverflow - I'm not sure if that would help anyways.

Minimal example:

```
class AsyncSend(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):

    async def connect(self):
        # Join group
        self.group_name = f"test"

        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        await self.accept()

        #Replicate non blocking call
        async for result in self.non_block():
            await self.send_task(result)

    async def non_block(self):
        for integer in range(4):
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            curTime = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
            print(f"{curTime} - {integer}")
            yield integer

    async def send_task(self, result):
        curTime = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        print(f"{curTime} - Send task called")
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.group_name, {
                'type': "transmit",
                'message': result,
            }
        )
        print("Finished sending")

    async def transmit(self, event):
        print(f"Received event to transmit...")

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Leave group
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
        self.group_name,
        self.channel_name
    )
```

Output:

```
10:23:21 - 0
10:23:21 - Send task called
Finished sending
10:23:22 - 1
10:23:22 - Send task called
Finished sending
10:23:23 - 2
10:23:23 - Send task called
Finished sending
10:23:24 - 3
10:23:24 - Send task called
Finished sending
Received event to transmit...
Received event to transmit...
Received event to transmit...
Received event to transmit...
```

Sadly running consumer threaded as suggested in: [How to multithread AsyncConsumer with Django Channels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52297958/how-to-multithread-asyncconsumer-with-django-channels) didn't work either.

I tried multiple implementations using run_in_executor and threadpoolexecutors, but I can't get it to work. In fact, it runs them sequentially rather than asynchronously.

Relevant amendments:

```
class AsyncSend(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5)

    async def connect(self):
        ...
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as pool:
            loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
            futures = []
            async for result in self.non_block():
                #await loop.create_task(self.send_task(result)) #No improvement over initial method
                future = await loop.run_in_executor(pool, self.send_task, result) #Same behaviour if pool is replaced with self.executor
                futures.append(future)
            try:
                results = await asyncio.gather(*futures) 
            except Exception as ex:
                print("Caught error executing task", ex)
                raise
```

```
12:43:39 - 0
12:43:40 - 1
12:43:41 - 2
12:43:42 - 3
12:43:42 - Send task called
Finished sending
12:43:42 - Send task called
Finished sending
12:43:42 - Send task called
Finished sending
12:43:42 - Send task called
Finished sending
Received event to transmit...
Received event to transmit...
Received event to transmit...
Received event to transmit...
```

I've also tried using uvicorn, but same behaviour each time.

**EDIT:** The issue seems to be that Channels is awaiting the function, so it won't process anything further from the queue (or channel) until the function returns.

To work around this, the code that calls the external process has been moved from the connect to the receive_json method. Furthermore, the external function call was placed inside a create_task so that receive_json returns immediately. Now it's working as expected, but I do wonder if there is a better way to achieve the same result?

```
    async def receive_json(self, text_data):
        asyncio.create_task(self.submit())

    async def submit(self):
        #Replicate non blocking call
        async for result in self.non_block():
            await self.send_task(result)
```

```
15:16:56 - 0
15:16:56 - Send task called
Finished sending
Received 0 to transmit...
15:16:57 - 1
15:16:57 - Send task called
Finished sending
Received 1 to transmit...
15:16:58 - 2
15:16:58 - Send task called
Finished sending
Received 2 to transmit...
15:16:59 - 3
15:16:59 - Send task called
Finished sending
Received 3 to transmit...
```

Comment: Wow this question and your inline answer saved me <3. Posting it as an accepted answer lol!